# Why does Append plus <img> tag return "use post request" error in JSFiddle?

Tags: jquery, image, append, jsfiddle

You can see my code here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/q2cxaes7/3/

This code works fine in my Firefox latest browser and validates perfectly according to JSHint.  But it returns "use post request" error in JSFiddle.  Does it give that error when you click the fiddle above?

Also, is this the best way to generate divs and programmatically increment the image name?

I use Fiddle to see the generated code . Neither View source nor Firebug shows the code because the slider script (not included in the fiddle) hides the slider container html, which is what this append script creates dynamically.

Here is a fiddle that works when the  reference is removed:
http://jsfiddle.net/zd83s20c/

Your input is appreciated.

```
<div id="actionman"></div>

$("#actionman").append('<div><img u="image" src="img/owls/owl-' + inum + '.jpg" /></div>' + '<div><img u="thumb" src="img/owls/owl-' + tnum + '.jpg" /></div>');
```

Comment: What is the question? Your code seems to work fine. Are you asking why you can't append an empty string?

Comment: because you are using relative paths for the image... the images are residing in your server so the server will find the image... but when you copy the same relative path to fiddle... it will look for paths like `http://fiddle.jshell.net/q2cxaes7/3/show/img/owls/owl-23.jpg` which is not valid... one way that is used is to use a service like placehold.it like - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7ocp472a/1/

Comment: I don't understand the question... the fiddle works as expected, and if images aren't loaded it's just because of the path pointing to nothing...

Comment: Why are you including fiddles that *don't* show the problem? How are we supposed to answer your question if you don't include this plugin you mention?

Comment: So the relative paths will always return a "use post request" error? How can I see exactly what div and <img> structure the code generated?

Comment: The Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q2cxaes7/3/ returns an error for me. Does it not error for you with a "use post request" error?

Comment: @Ban-Stoning no it doesn't and jsfiddle works as expected

Comment: I see. I tried again and this time I did not receive an error either. Perhaps the Fiddle was glitchy, but it is working now. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you  Arun P Johny for the placeholder idea.

Answer (score 0):

The JsFiddle was returning a "use post request" error at first. But later, after a few refreshes, it no longer erred in that fashion. Thank you for your help parsing this out.